# A comment is better than my answer - should I remove the answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, etiquette, answers-as-comments

I answered a question, and a user later added a correct comment that would actually make a better answer than mine. Should I remove my answer?

Comment: Alternatively, you could edit your answer and give credit to the comment author for the suggestion - that would seem a constructive approach.

Comment: Establish dominance by incorporating the comment into your answer, then flagging it as ‘no longer needed’.

Comment: @W.O. I would use your comment as plan B. As plan A, I would first comment, at-mentioning the author of the useful comment, thanking them for the this comment, and suggesting that they convert their comment to an answer. If such plan A does not work, use plan B.

Answer (score 9):

**If you want to be a purist about it:**

No, don't remove your answer.  You've *answered* the question.  There's no guarantee that the comment will be around tomorrow™, so if your answer is deleted, then we'd lose that information.

**If you want to be practical about this:**

Copy the comment into a new Community Wiki answer (just tick the box down at the bottom-right of the answer text box) and be sure to cite that it was from this person in the comments. Doesn't mean you have to delete *your* answer, though.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to remove your answer when you have an opportunity to improve it.

The commenter has provided good content but has declined to write an answer, at least to this point, so I think you should incorporate their comment into your answer, and give them credit for it by saying it came from their comment.

If the commenter later uses their own content to write an answer, then you may decide to delete yours at that later time.

Make no mistake, for focused Q&A we want answers to be written and for that to be done sooner rather than later.  Comments on posts are intended for seeking clarifications and making suggestions for post improvement; they are not intended to be a permanent part of any SE sites.

[@W.O. wrote a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388537/a-comment-is-better-than-my-answer-should-i-remove-the-answer/388558#comment1295470_388537) before I wrote and posted the first version of my answer but my answer was written and posted before reading that comment.  The thoughts expressed by their comment and my answer have some overlap.

Comment: Oi, that's my idea! No, it's OK, you can have it for free - this time ;)